# Replace all uppercase text to smallcaps AND wdTitleSentence

Tags: vba, ms-word, uppercase

I'm stuck with this problem for the past two days and I can't find a way to overcome it.
I've a document (400 pages) where I want to replace ALL the uppercase words to SmallCaps AND set the text as "title sentence".
When I register a macro, I found the commands that I need:

```
Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleSentence
Selection.Font.SmallCaps = wdToggle
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to apply these commands only to the uppercase words and NOT to the selected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a wildcard search, though you'll need to be careful how you specify it other wise you could change every capital letter in the document to small caps.

```
Sub ConvertUpperCase()
   Dim findRange As Range
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      'find at least two consecutive capital letters
      .Text = "[A-Z]{2,}"
      .MatchWildcards = True
      Do While .Execute = True
         With findRange
            .Case = wdTitleSentence
            .Font.SmallCaps = True
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         End With
      Loop
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @michele - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Just one thing: If the macro returns "runtime error 5560" when you run it, replace comma (,) with semicolon (;) in "[A-Z]{2,}"

Comment: @Michele - are you using a non-English version of Office? The reference I use for wildcards does not list semicolon as valid - see [the Word MVP's guide to using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)

Comment: Yes, an Italian version. Another way to bypass the runtime error is to change the system language to English, but it's easier to replace the comma