# Word VBA Replace a certain format with a different format

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

In a large Word document I want to find instances of text formatted in the **All Caps font** (i.e. the underlying characters themselves are lower case, they are just shown upper case) and **convert** these bits to **actual upper case characters**.

With the help of ChatGPT (I know...) I could get the following script running, but it does not go into the loop:

```
Sub ConvertToAllCaps()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    
    ' Set the document object
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Set the range to search in the entire document
    Set rng = doc.Content
    
    With rng.Find
        ' Set the find parameters
        .Font.AllCaps = True
        
        ' Execute the find operation
        Do While .Execute
            ' Clear formatting before converting to all caps
            rng.ClearFormatting
            ' Convert the found text to all caps
            rng.Case = wdUpperCase
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

This code stops after the first successful conversion, i.e. it finds the first x connected bits of text that are formatted in all caps but then stops searching for more such text. I then played around with many suggestions by others with similar problem I could find on the internet, but nothing worked. The closest I got, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387914/word-vba-loop-do-if-find-found) thread, was:

```
Sub ConvertToAllCaps()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    
    bFound = True
    
    ' Set the document object
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Set the range to search in the entire document
    Set rng = doc.Content
    
    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    Do While bFound
        With rng.Find
        ' Set the find parameters
            .Font.AllCaps = True
 
            rng.ClearFormatting
            rng.Case = wdUpperCase

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            bFound = .Execute
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

At least this made Word crash, so I know it went into the loop :) Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: You are using `rng.ClearFormatting` but rng is the entire document - so once you've found an instance there are no more to find.
I suspect that you want `Selection.ClearFormatting`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Based on your suggestion I started trying to implement the selection function, only to accidentally notice that in my first code I could just remove the ClearFormatting bit entirely and it would still work - just once. I played around for an hour, got interrupted, and now @taller gave a working example already...

Comment: You really don’t need any code for this. You can do this just by using Find and Replace.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Well... yes, probably I could go through every letter of the alphabet in all caps font and replace it with the corresponding upper case letter in neutral non-all caps. I totally forgot about this work around, I was focused on more elegant solutions  thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need to use `Do While`. `ReplaceAll` is more efficient.
- `rng.ClearFormatting` should be `.Replacement.ClearFormatting`.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Replacement.ClearFormatting method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.replacement.clearformatting?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm162594836)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Find.ClearFormatting method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.clearformatting?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm162529311)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Font.AllCaps property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.font.allcaps?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm156369030)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub ReplaceAllCap()
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.AllCaps = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.AllCaps = False
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Update:

> Question: but now I notice it doesn't convert the text to upper case.

```vb
Sub ReplaceAllCap()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.AllCaps = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.AllCaps = False
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        Do While .Execute
            Selection.Range.Case = wdUpperCase
            Selection.Collapse Word.wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Taller, thank you so much! At first I thought this has solved it completely, but now I notice it doesn't convert the text to upper case. I was trying to implement this myself, but it seems this needs a totally different approach: You use the selection object for everything, whereas the wdUpperCase function needs to be applied to a range object  So I feel like I can't even alter your code...

Comment: This works like a charm now! Thank you so much! Based on your solution I was able to alter somebody else's code and it did work for me - but much safer to take your solution. If I wasn't new here I would upvote your answer, I hope somebody else will do. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to configure all settings of the `Find` object in this scenario. The main distinction is that my code disables Font.AllCaps for the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I came up with a solution myself, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968751/replace-all-uppercase-text-to-smallcaps-and-wdtitlesentence) thread and the (first) code from taller above. It does work for me, however, for the record books let me still stress this thread has shown that taller knows more what he's doing than I do ;-) so you'd better take his code.

```
Sub ConvertAllCaps ()
   Dim findRange As Range
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Font.AllCaps = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      Do While .Execute = True
         With findRange
            .Case = wdUpperCase
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         End With
      Loop
   End With
End Sub
```